# Conserving Momentum from UIScrollView to inner UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, twitter, uiscrollview

I'm looking to implement something very similar to the iOS Twitter Profile page, as seen here:

[image: Twitter iOS Profile Page]
<sub>(source: [twimg.com](https://g.twimg.com/blog/blog/image/iOS_bellbird_275px.gif))</sub>

Based on what I can see, they have a UIView at the top, and a UIScrollView covering the entire view with a UITableView within the UIScrollView.

This is a tutorial on replicating it, and can be seen here: http://www.thinkandbuild.it/implementing-the-twitter-ios-app-ui/

The issue I've run into is how to maintain the momentum from scrolling on the UIScrollView vs. the UITableView.  With the Twitter Profile page, you can scroll in one smooth swipe and it will move the UIScrollView up (showing the UITableView more) and any 'momentum' that is still there will start scrolling the UITableView.

I assume this must be done within the scrollViewDidScroll and check for any offset left over after reaching the bottom of the UIScrollView.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == self.myScrollView {
        var maxOffset = 25.0
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        self.myScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -min(offset, maxOffset), view.frame.width, view.frame.height)
        if offset - maxOffset > 0 {
            self.myTableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0,offset-maxOffset), animated:true)
        }
  }
```

This kind of works, although it certainly isn't smooth and doesn't appear as though it's maintaining momentum.

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you ever found a solution for this – I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I didn't.  I got as close as I could where the ScrollView on top of the tableView scrolls and is limited.  Once it's limited then the scrollview is disabled and the tableview is enabled, and vice versa going back.  It's pretty decent, but not great.

Comment: Found a solution, sort of. I put my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think twitter's profile uses two scrollviews. It uses one tableview and adjusts the scroll indicator dynamically with the `scrollIndicatorOffsets` property. If you look closely at the scroll indicator you can see it shimmy a bit as you start to scroll up, which is consistent with this approach.